# Probability of drawing 4 real coins

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Two fake coins of the same weight are on the same box as eight real coins.
> The weight of each of the fake coins is different as the real ones. We
> randomly select a pair of coins without replacement out of the ten.
>
> Then we select another pair out of the remaining eight.
>
> What is the probability that the four coins we got are real, knowing that
> the combined weight of the first pair is the same as the second pair?

I named the following events as:

A = "the four coins are real".

B = "the weight of the first pair is the same as the weight of the second pair"

C = "both pairs containing a fake coin and a real coin"

D = "both pairs contain only real coins"

Of course, $B = C \cup D$.

So, $$P(A |C \cup D)= \frac{P(A \cap (B \cup C))}{P(C \cup D)}=\frac{P(D)}{P(C \cup D)}$$

Now

- $P(D)=P(\text{"I get two real coins on the first pair"})P(\text{"I get two real coins on the second pair"})$

To calculate this, I used a random variable $X \sim \text{hypergeometric}(10, 8, 2)$

So $P(\text{"I get two real coins on the first pair"})=P(X=2)=\frac{8 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2}=\frac{28}{45}$

And $Y \sim \text{hypergeometric}(8, 6, 2)$

So $P(\text{"I get two real coins on the second pair"})=P(X=2)=\frac{6 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2}=\frac{15}{28}$

$\Rightarrow \boxed{ P(D)=\frac{28}{45} \cdot \frac{15}{28} = \frac{1}{3}}$

$P(C \cup D)=P(C)+P(D)-P(C \cap D)$ with $P(C \cap D)=0$

So $\boxed{P(C)=\frac{2}{10} \cdot \frac{8}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{7}{7}=\frac{1}{45}}$ (First I select a fake coin (so I have a probability of $\frac{2}{10}$), then I select a real one (I have a probability of $\frac{8}{9}$ as I already took a coin), and so on).

Finally,

$$\boxed{P(A | C \cup D) = \frac{1/3}{1/45 + 1/3}=\frac{15}{16}}$$

I don't know where is my mistake, the correct answer is under the spoiler markup.

> The correct answer is $\frac{15}{19}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $C$ you don't have to pick the coins in the order fake-real-fake-real. There are actually four possible orders of fake and real. So $P(C)=\frac{4}{45}$. This should point you toward the right answer.